# How to avoid sending ethers from any address on a local testnet (Ganache)?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ganache

I am developing a crypto crowdfunding website. The smart contract is based on [the work](https://github.com/RedSquirrelTech/hoscdev/blob/master/chapter-7/fundraiser/contracts/Fundraiser.sol).

My development environment is Ganache + Truffle + Node.js + MetaMask.

When my client code is as follows, everything works fine. I can send some ethers from my MetaMask account (i.e. accounts[0]) to the Fundraiser contract.

```
  const submitFunds = async () => {
    const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const deployedNetwork = FundraiserContract.networks[networkId];
    const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(FundraiserContract.abi, contractAddress);

    await instance.methods.donate().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: donationAmount,
      gas: 650000
    });
  };
```

However, if I change `const web3 = new Web3(provider);` to `const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545');`, then I can send ethers to the contract from any other account on the Ganache testnet, such as accounts[1], accounts[2], or accounts[3], as long as I change the client code. These accounts are not in my MetaMask wallet.

How can I make sure a user can only send ethers to the contract using his/her own account?

Thanks.